# Does the TLS version of the email client matter?

Tags: ssl, smtp

We are using Goldmine and Sendblaster to send emails to two different SMTP servers. We have been advised by someone that there is a need to upgrade Goldmine because older version don't support TLS1.2.

So does this mean that when you send a message from your PC to an SMTP server which already has TLS1.2, the TLS version of the sending software also matters? Will the receiving server be checking for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server will commonly support multiple TLS versions at the same time, i.e. typically TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 and maybe also TLS 1.3. Similar a client will usually support multiple TLS versions. Within the TLS handshake client and server basically agree on the best version both can support.

If there is no common TLS version the TLS handshake will fail though. This can happen for example if the server was hardened to only allow TLS 1.2 and better (i.e. TLS 1.3) but the client is too outdated to even support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Thank you. If the handshake fails because the client is outdated then will the SMTP server still send out the message with a TLS encryption and thus will the receiver's server or client know that the initial handshake failed?

I.e. will servers which reject emails from older versions of TLS, block emails from a client with outdated TLS even though the SMTP server had TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3?

Comment: @d786b09987n: if the handshake fails the client will not be able to submit its message in the first place, i.e. no mail will be send.

Comment: Thanks again! Is it possible for the TLS version to be upgraded during transmission. E.g. the initial client to server handshake uses TLS1.1 and then the server uses TLS1.2 to send the email? Would the recipient then know that the earlier part of the transmission was in TLS1.1?

Comment: @d786b09987n: Each TCP/TLS connection between the mail transfer agents (MTA) is independent (which also means that each MTA can read the mail in clear).It is possible that initial delivery is done with TLS 1.1 and the next step with TLS 1.2 or even with no TLS at all. There can be information in the `Received` header of the mail which reflect the TLS protocol version but this is not always the case. Thus the recipient might know or it might not know which TLS protocols were involved in the delivery.